# Change the wording of the registration page

Tags: 7, users

I want to change the wording of the default registration page.  I found some posts about completely customizing/re-theming the page but they seemed like total overkill for what I had in mind.  
Specifically, this is designed to be a website for only students that go to my school, so I have already set it up so that you can only register with *@myschool.edu* email address.  But I can't figure out how to let people know that on the registration page.  I am surprised you can't edit the registration page through the configuration module at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to add a few directions at the top/bottom, try creating a custom
 block.  Create a custom block with the instructions you want to add.  On the block configuration page, you can set the path to display only on certain pages.  Set that to `user/register`.  Then all you have to do is make sure the block is appearing in the appropriate region in your theme.

Comment: Huzzah that worked!  Seems like an odd way to do it, but I suppose it works for now.  I am still very new to Drupal, so I would like to avoid diving in the PHP code until I am a little more familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely more advanced ways, like using PHP templates in your theme, but in a pinch you can always use a block.

Comment: Still find it surprising you can't do it within the Drupal menus.